# Query to Return 0 or Null value if there is no data in a table for a particular date in the Snowflake table

Tags: sql, datetime, group-by, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do a 6 month look back on how many times a user has logged in during the time and how to return 0 as the count for a missing date.

For example,I need to return 0 as the count(distinct visits) on 02/21 & 02/22 for the below data set.

| DT | User | Count(distinct Visits) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-20 | Alec | 2 |
| 2023-02-23 | Alec | 10 |

This is the query I am using :

```
Select Visit_DT, count(distinct visits)
From User_Data 
Where Visit_DT >= dateadd(month,-6,current_date()) and 
User = ‘Alec’
Group by 1 order by 1 desc;
```

This has to be executed multiple times in a day for different users, what’s the most cost effective way to achieve it.

Comment: Start by creating a calendar table and/or generate one as part of the query (such as CTE for your calendar, and a CTE for your user data), then select from calendar and left join to user. For the calendar, look up snowflake's equivalent to generate_series, which could be a recursive CTE or other method.

Answer (score 0):

Better way for answer to this question use temp table

first you create temp table of list dates between current date and 6 month ago

then you must join your table with temp table

and join your table with temp table

Finally you use group by for calcuate count visits

```
WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS
(    SELECT cast(dateadd(month,-6,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
    FROM ListDates 
    WHERE AllDates < cast(GETDATE()  AS DATE)
    )
SELECT AllDates
into #ListDates
        FROM ListDates
       option (maxrecursion 0)


Select a.AllDates, count(distinct visits)
From #User_Data 
right join(
    select * from #ListDates a  
    
)a on  a.AllDates=Visit_DT

--Where Visit_DT >= dateadd(month,-6,GETDATE())
Group by a.AllDates order by a.AllDates desc;
```

You can to insert the basic data with the following codes

```
create table #User_Data(Visit_DT date,[User] nvarchar(100),Visits int)
insert into #User_Data
(Visit_DT,[User],Visits)
select '2023-04-11' as Visit_DT      ,'Alec' [user],1
union select '2023-04-11' as Visit_DT,'Alec' [user],4
union select '2023-04-07' as Visit_DT,'testa' [user],7 
union select '2023-04-07' as Visit_DT,'test' [user],8 
union select '2023-04-01' as Visit_DT,'Alec' [user],15
```

Answer (score 0):

first generate a series of dates.

```
 select -1 + row_number() over (order by 0) i, start_date + i dte
        from (select '1980-01-01'::date start_date, '2099-01-01'::date end_date)
        join table(generator(rowcount => 1000000)) x
        qualify i < 1 + end_date - start_date
```

Then left join your SQL to get count of visits. Generate series till the day you want to.

Whole SQL will be -

```
with visits as ( 
Select Visit_DT, count(distinct visits) cnt 
From User_Data 
Where Visit_DT >= dateadd(month,-6,current_date())
Group by 1 ),
ser as ( select -1 + row_number() over (order by 0) i, start_date + i dte
        from (select '1980-01-01'::date start_date, '2099-01-01'::date end_date)
        join table(generator(rowcount => 1000000)) x
        qualify i < 1 + end_date - start_date)

select ser.dte as dt, visits.cnt 
from ser
left join visits.visit_dt=ser.dte 
where ser.dte <'2023-12-31'  -- this shows data till 2023 change this date filter as per your need
```